# Correct positioning of two divs, split

Tags: wordpress, css

What would be the correct/best way to locate the information below, split between two divs.

You can see the page in question here:

http://property.begbies-traynor.com/sale/the-camelot-hotel/

As you will see, the top area is split into two sections. One on the right for the primary property image, and one on the left that contains the property features.

I have tried using Floats but it seems to be erratic on how its displaying.

What would be the best way to split those two pieces of information?

At present they are set as two separate divs, with one set to float:right;

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#split` needs to be `float: left;`

Then the total width of `#split` and `#split-two` needs to be narrower than the container.

Finally, you'll need a clearing element, either using a [suitable clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), or a cheap and dirty `<br style="clear:both;" />` inside the container but after `#split` and `#split-two`

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I thought I had tried the various float: commands but obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want the property image on the *right* and the column of information on the *left*, but in your sample you've `float:right` on the `#split-two` information column.

If you do want the image on the right and column on the left you want to make the following changes:

```
#split {
float: right;
}

#split-two {
float: none;
}
```

and in the html:

```
<div id="split-two" class="clearfix">   
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your style.

```
#split {
width: 340px;
float: left;
}
```